# Setting compiler and linker directories via pragma in Visual C++

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, pragma

Is it possible in Visual C++ to set additional include directories and additional libary directories in the source code itself, through pragma definitions (similarly to #pragma comment(lib, "xxx.lib") to link specific libs)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latest list of available pragmas for Visual C++ [is available here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/pragma-directives-and-the-pragma-keyword). I don't see anything there for specifying library paths or anything else like that.

Comment: The link is no longer valid :(

Comment: @YePhIcK - Hmm. Latest-greatest link for this seems to be [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/pragma-directives-and-the-pragma-keyword). However, that (like this question from 8 years ago) doesn't specify which version of the compiler its good for. At the risk of no longer making it a good answer to the OP, I'll go ahead and update the answer since what's linked there now isn't any good to anyone. Hopefully by now he already got the answer he needed anyway. :-)

Comment: I had that same question (which is why I got here) and I have confirmed that there is **still** no way to specify the "/LIBPATH" with a `#pragma` as of MSVC 2017 (15.5.3)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this. [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9x1s805(VS.71).aspx) is the list of all supported pragma directives.

Answer (score 0):

All of these answers are very VERY old. Here is the latest working link to the list of Visual C++ Pragmas, circa 2020 and Visual C++ 2019:

[Visual C++ Pragmas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/pragma-directives-and-the-pragma-keyword?view=vs-2019)

More importantly, once the above link stop working like all links before it, here is the search phrase you can use with Google to find a working link to that page:

```
"Visual C++" "section pragma"
```

Here is a link to automate the Google search (which may also stop working in the future, but you can always resort to the above search text and do the search manually):

[Google search for: "Visual C++" "section pragma"](https://www.google.com/search?q=visual%20c%2B%2B%20pragma%20section)